# Getting current Bitcoin Fees from Command LIne?

Tags: transaction-fees, cli

I have a shell script, that fetches current bitcoin fees from https://bitcoinfees.21.co/ with this command:

```
curl -sS -L --insecure https://bitcoinfees.21.co/api/v1/fees/recommended
```

When I run this command from (Central-) Europe, I never encountered an issue. Now I am in Africa, and obviously there is JavaScript injected by Cloudflare, asking for a Captcha. This prevents to get the values with a  shell script (command line). Is there a way around it, or are there other services for an overview of fees for BTC?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a running instance of Bitcoin Core, you can use `estimatesmartfee` to get a fee rate estimate.